# Storing data Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, azure

I'm developing a Windows 8 Application (C#/XAML). A brief outline of the application:

A user creates a match (Sport, League, Team1, Team2, Forecast_score). Another user can join the match and give his own Forecast_score.

This is how I see it: **Correct me if I'm wrong**

- Table 1: Player (PlayerId, PlayerName)
- Table 2: Match (MatchId, Sport, League, Team1, Team2, Forecast)
- Table 3: PlayerMatch (PlayerId, MatchId, Forecast)

At this moment I'm using a Windows Azure Mobile Service to store the data in **1 table**. **Not sure if this is the best way?**

Anyone knows a better solution? I would like differenct tables (linked) but don't know if this is possible in Azure?

Comment: You can open the database and put on foreign keys on the tables, but I have not tried this and do not know how mobile services work if starting to change the database manually.

Comment: If you are familiar with Entity Framework, you can use that instead of mobile services and create your own database scheme. You offcause loose some of the easy integration with other platforms that mobile services provide out of the box.